# Stop HCE if sdk < Kitkat

Tags: android, sdk, hce

I have a weird question. I want to know if I can block the hce feature/service if the device sdk is smaller than the required Kitkat sdk? 
At the moment I stop my HCe service at the startup of my app but I am not sure if thats the correct way

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
                //Disable Hce service if sdk < 19
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("at.ventopay.mocca.hce_service", "at.ventopay.mocca.hce_service.MyHostApduService"));
                stopService(intent);
            }
```

It works like a charm but I m just not convinced that I should even do this.
My question now is:       Can I block the HCE feature if the device sdk is wrong or does my device need to be  >=Kitkat if I use HCE?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to explicitly stop the service for API versions < 19?

Comment: I wanted to stop the HCE service if the device doesnt support it. I need to stop it because my App doest require HCE feature but uses it if possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to stop your HCE service on platform versions < 19. If your Android version does not support HCE/use your HCE service, it will not even generate an event that starts the service component in the first place.

Your service is registered with the system through a section like this in your manifest:

```
<service android:name="..." android:exported="true"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
               android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
</service>
```

So the service can only be started by binding to it with the intent action `android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE` (or with an explcit intent for your service component). Moreover, only an application that holds the permission `android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE` can do that.

As a platform prior to Kitkat neither knows about that intent nor about that permission, it will not cause your service to be started.

Comment: @miron123 In fact if your HCE service would be bound to on a platform < 19, it should crash as the `HostApduService` class would not be part of the framework on that platform.